# Missing tiles and controls in Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I recently upgraded a mapping app to the Google Maps JS API v3. It was working perfectly, but now the maps are missing their tiles and controls. The map with the missing elements is visible at:

http://test.mapping.cit.cornell.edu/publiclabs/map/

The surprising thing is that I'm not seeing any JS errors or 404s in my dev console. Also, the `div`s for the tiles are present (see the screenshot below).

Has something changed in the API in the last couple of months that would cause this behavior?

[image: divs_are_there]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'G_NORMAL_MAP'` is not a built-in `mapTypeId` for a V3-map.

Built-in mapTypeIds are

```
google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP//this is the default
google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes

There was an update yesterday, maybe that's  the source of the issue, but it has been a real long time now since V2 has been gone, it's your fault when you didn't use this time to update your code

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Dr.Molle. I had a database update script that had not been run in the testing environment.